# VirtualBox Host-only: guests can't talk between themselves?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm using a host-only network with VirtualBox on macOS Sierra, my guests are Ubuntu. My **Host** (*192.168.56.1*) can ping both **Guest A** (*192.168.56.100*) and **Guest B** (*192.168.56.101*). Each guest can ping **Host**, but *guests can't ping each other*.

**Guest A** routing table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

**Guest B** routing table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

Because **Host** can talk to guests and each guest can talk to **Host**, I get a feeling that the host is not forwarding traffic between the guests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was using `192.168.56.100` for `Guest A`. On VirtualBox's default configuration, that IP is already used for the DHCP server in `vboxnet0`.

I changed the guest's IP to an unused one and `Guest A` and `Guest B` could then talk to each other.

This wouldn't happen if you're using DHCP for your guests as VBox won't assign `192.168.56.100`. You would only enounter this issue if you were setting static IPs for your guests like I did.